# How can I clean up compiler-file*.d in IntelliJ CLion?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion, compilation-database

I created a compilation database for a large C  project in IntelliJ CLion.  So far it's been working well, but my directories are filling up with compiler-file*.d files.  Is there a way to clean them up?

Comment: Please contact clion-support@jetbrains.com